# Anyone know how to install dig into the codebuild v5 image on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, dig, buildspec

So, I want to install the dig command because it's not available in the Codebuild v5 image.

I tried to do:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

but it errors out with an `exit status 100`.

What's the best way to get this utility in my image with the `buildspec.yml`?

Comment: You need to update your question with the actual error message (that's in the CodeBuild logs). My guess is that it's because the CodeBuild images use `yum` as their package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I could install `dnsutils` the following way:

```
plases:
  install:
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get -y install dnsutils
```